# Ошибка E0167 аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "char *"

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите, пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Самое сложное, а именно подключение библиотеки я выполнила, а эта проблема мешает

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "hunspelldll.h"

using namespace std;
void main(){
    Hunspell* spellObj = (Hunspell*)hunspell_initialize("ru_RU.aff","ru_RU.dic");
    //  ^change * type        ^cast returned void* to type that will be used later

    char str[60];

    cin >> str;

    int result = hunspell_spell(spellObj, str);

    if (result == 0)
        cout << "Spelling error!";
    else
        cout << "Correct Spelling!";

    hunspell_uninitialize(spellObj /*SpellObject is undefined*/);
    //                        ^use correct variable
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, `hunspell_initialize` принимает `char*`, а не `const char*`. Но об этом код умалчивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы передаёте в функцию строковый литерал, он имеет тип `const char*`. Если же функция принимает параметр типа `char*`, то надо передать ей такую строку, которую можно изменять. Например, так:

```
char c1[] = "ru_RU.aff";
char c2[] = "ru_RU.dic";
hunspell_initialize(c1, c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hunspell* spellObj = (Hunspell*)hunspell_initialize((char*)"ru_RU.aff",(char*)"ru_RU.dic");
```

Comment: Когда нет уверенности, что внутри функции не будет попытки изменить переданную строку, так делать не стоит.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]